# Generating a UUID with the NPM package UUID?

Tags: typescript, uuid

Trying to generate a set of UUIDs using the [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package on NPM.  With typescript I try this:

```
  import v1 from "uuid/v1";

  console.log(v1());
  console.log(v1());
  console.log(v1());
  console.log(v1());
  console.log(v1());
```

This prints:

```
ef1f74d0-aff3-11e8-9466-0db0429140ee
ef1f74d1-aff3-11e8-9466-0db0429140ee
ef1f74d2-aff3-11e8-9466-0db0429140ee
ef1f74d3-aff3-11e8-9466-0db0429140ee
ef1f74d4-aff3-11e8-9466-0db0429140ee
```

So even though each console log calls `v1()` it still generates the same UUID.  Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like v1 is time stamp based so calling it so frequently would result in the same UUID being generated.

Comment: Those UUIDs aren't the same: the 8th character is changing.

Comment: OK - Got it now - I glanced at a few numbers which were 81d6a910-aff4-11e8-8c7d-5547b5471796 and 81d6a911-aff4-11e8-8c7d-5547b5471796, so they looked identical, thus I thought something was off.  Thanks for the extra eyeballs!  Especially late monday night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those aren't the same uuids. Notice the first part of each uuid is different

`ef1f74d0
ef1f74d1
ef1f74d2
ef1f74d3
ef1f74d4`

Comment: Sheez - THANK YOU - I need to get some sleep :)

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us